# Flex 4.5.1 runtime errors, ant task compiling

Tags: apache-flex, ant, compilation, flex4.5

I am having problems with my ant task or my Flex 4.5.1 compiler configuration.

I debug my app with the same Flex builder version (4.5.1) with Eclipse and there are no problems. I build my Flex app with Jenkins and the Flex 4.5.1 SDK.

There are no compilations errors but when I start the built app, I am having runtime errors that seemed to be related with some of my embedded images.
The error messages look like

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: The variable ApplicationBackgroundSkin__embed_mxml__images_bg_png_87911483 is not defined.
```

I have an ApplicationBackgroundSkin class with :

```
<s:BitmapFill source="@Embed('/images/bg.png')" fillMode="repeat"/>
```

I found this [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f2c.html) and I supposed it could be a localization or ressource bundle problem as I compile my app using the "FR_fr" locale but I didn't find what I was supposed to do to solve it.

Comment: Hm, that's weird.  An embedded image will normally cause an error on compile.  Can you show us the Ant build file?  It's not a locale/resource bundle problem since you're not using resource manager.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just solved my problem and you're right it was the ant build file. I had to modify it because I changed the flex builder version (4.1->4.5) during the dev. So I must do a custom compilation.

Comment: Kenny: What kind of changes did you made to get this work?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, turns out that in the .actionScriptProperties file the targetPlayerVersion was set to 0.0.0 in the compiler tag. So changed it to 10.0.2 and fixed the problem